# validate that image exist when updating kubernetes deployment

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, google-kubernetes-engine

when updating deployment with a none-exist image, Kubernetes first will start terminating the existing pod and will end up with a broken deployment.
 is it possible to tell kubectl to validate/pull the image before terminating existing pod?

Comment: Run more than a single replica? So only one will get terminated.

Comment: well, that's for sure, but still, I'll end up with fewer pods than I desire

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following. When you say "Kubernetes first will start terminating the existing pod" this suggests that you're using a `Recreate` strategy (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#strategy)? Because the default is `RollingUpdate` and that means (along with the probes) that only if the new pods are alive and ready, the old pods are deleted. Can you clarify this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to change the `strategy.rollingUpdate.maxUnavailable` to 0

```
strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 0
    type: RollingUpdate
```

I think that the default of `strategy.rollingUpdate.maxUnavailable` is 1

Thanks Michael Hausenblas

Answer (score 0):

While I have not tested this I think in theory this should work:

You can use the admission controller `AlwaysPullImages` and a deployment strategy where at least one pod is up. The admission controller ensures that images are `Always` pulled before the pod is started.

To enable this admission controller you will have to enable flag at Kubernetes API server like [from this link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/#how-do-i-turn-on-an-admission-controller):

```
kube-apiserver --enable-admission-plugins=AlwaysPullImages,LimitRanger
```

Answer (score 0):

Implementing Liveness / Readiness will ensure that old pod gets terminated only if the new pod is healthy.